# White screen of Death after clearing cache, can't find a way to get the site back up

Tags: database, caching

My problem is that I keep getting the white screen of Death ever since I cleared the cache of my Drupal website.

The error is the following :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function uc_address_property_info() in 
sites/all/modules/ubercart/shipping/uc_shipping/uc_shipping.rules.inc on line 12
```

It happened after I cleared all the cache using the button from the Drupal configuration page. I'm pretty sure the Ubercart Store module is enabled, and I tried clearing the cache from the database already. Before clearing the cache, the site was working fine. The only thing I did is trying to hide some profile2 fields that I created and since they were still there, I thought that clearing the cache would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Drush, I would try doing another cache-clear. If that doesn't work, I would also try a [registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild).

Other than that, just make sure that file exists and that function exists.

Comment: I tried both and it still didn't work. The uc_store.module file exists and the function too.

Comment: Did you get any additional information out of the registry rebuild?